Invalid $addFields :: caused by :: undefined variable: setNumberPart
I've been developing an app to track my trading card collection. I'm attempting to use an aggregate pipeline for sorting cards at the database level since this app will contain a ton of data. I'm very new to aggregates, and I keep running into the issue where my setNumberPart variable is out of scope when referenced and I can't seem to figure out a way to be within scope. Here is my pipeline code:
        const pipeline = [
          { $match: query }, // Match documents based on the query

          {
            $addFields: {
              numericSetNumber: {
                $let: {
                  vars: {
                    // Extract the relevant part of setNumber based on prefix
                    setNumberPart: {
                      $cond: [
                        { $regexMatch: { input: "$setNumber", regex: /^GG/ } },
                        { $arrayElemAt: [{ $split: ["$setNumber", "/"] }, 0] },
                        {
                          $cond: [
                            {
                              $regexMatch: {
                                input: "$setNumber",
                                regex: /^TG/,
                              },
                            },
                            {
                              $arrayElemAt: [
                                { $split: ["$setNumber", "/"] },
                                0,
                              ],
                            },
                            {
                              $cond: [
                                {
                                  $regexMatch: {
                                    input: "$setNumber",
                                    regex: /^SWSH/,
                                  },
                                },
                                {
                                  $arrayElemAt: [
                                    { $split: ["$setNumber", " "] },
                                    -1,
                                  ],
                                },
                                "$setNumber", // Default case if no prefix matches
                              ],
                            },
                          ],
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                    // Remove non-numeric characters from setNumberPart
                    cleanedSetNumber: {
                      $replaceAll: {
                        input: "$$setNumberPart",
                        find: "[^0-9]", // Pattern to keep only numeric characters
                        replacement: "",
                      },
                    },
                  },
                  in: {
                    // Convert cleaned number to integer or default to 0 if empty
                    $cond: [
                      {
                        $regexMatch: {
                          input: "$$cleanedSetNumber",
                          regex: /^\d+$/, // Ensure it's numeric
                        },
                      },
                      { $toInt: { $ifNull: ["$$cleanedSetNumber", "0"] } },
                      0,
                    ],
                  },
                },
              },
            },
          },

          ...(Object.keys(sortStage).length > 0 ? [{ $sort: sortStage }] : []),
          { $skip: offset },
          { $limit: limit },
        ];

Any help getting this variable to stop being undefined is much appreciated!
I tried adding another $let inside the cleanedSetNumber variable and defined $$setNumberPart there, but it still showed as undefined.

I think this should be what you need, by moving the logic for setNumberPart into the cleanedSetNumber input. Demo
